# How to implement group chatting/message-board mobile app?

Tags: iphone, notifications, messaging, xmpp

I am trying to write a iPhone group chatting/message-board app which will have a backend component. I expect users to register with our system and start posting messages on chatrooms/message-boards. These message-boards can have more than 2 individuals, must support real time notifications and should be accessible from any other clients (like web) as well.

I stumbled upon http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/ . I realize that XMPP is a very attractive proposition for our needs but I am seriously worried about the infrastructure complexities and scale issues. Besides, XMPP has way too much to offer for my needs. Looks like, XMPP might be the only choice for my pleasure in pain, but I wanted to see what you experts have to say on this.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

My advice is: whichever protocol you're choosing, *do not try to invent your own protocol*. Go for XMPP or if you can find an alternative which you find more compelling, use that. Especially if there's already a nice framework for you to use. Why ? Because a single developer new to a field is seldom smarter than a bunch of people with experience ;-) Make use of other peoples' experience by using an established protocol, and make use of existing frameworks to avoid coding mistakes and investing a lot of time to solve a problem yet again that was already solved.

That being said, XMPP is widely deployed and thus would make for a good choice if you later plan to write additional clients for other platforms or want to have third-party clients connect to your server.

Comment: This is a very good answer. Moreover XMPP is modular. If you don't need a feature, don't activate it on the server or don't use it.

Comment: Thanks DarkDust. This helps! I will try to share what I learn.